# Excel 2013 not displaying Form Controls (Not a hide/visible issue)

Tags: excel, forms, controls, display

A single machine, Windows 10 & Excel 2013, will no longer correctly display spreadsheets that have Form Control objects. ActiveX objects display correctly.

**Form Control combo box**

[image: Form Control combo box]

**ActiveX combo box**

[image: ActiveX combo box]

Have removed and reinstalled Office, removed and reinstalled Visual Studio 2010, followed suggestions for FM20.dll and FM20ENU.dll, all to no avail. All updates to Office and Windows 10. Updated video drivers, checked Excel options and settings. No add-ins. No 3rd party Office or Excel tools.

The form can not be changed, easily and since other computers display correctly, don’t want to spend much more time on this. But finding out the root cause would be of great help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you checked your `Selection Pane...` to ensure all form control objects are not hidden by accident? Is there any `vba` that may trigger some unexpected actions?

Comment: Controls are not hidden. As you can see from the first image, the ‘control’ is visible. That is what displays. Sometimes, when you select it, it displays (mostly correct,) but not exactly as it should. I.e., if you select to ‘edit the text for a check box,’ you can see the box and text correctly. Clicking away from it, completely disappears. The combo box turns into a giant ‘down arrow,’ when selected.

Comment: If it only happens to your computer but others can run the excel sheet and see the form controls without such issue, you may want to compare your computer's RAM and performance score with the others. I guess it is not an issue within Excel.